# ¿Como retorno un valor en un metodo de Vue.js que usa axios?

Tags: vue.js, axios

Mi método se mira así:

```
createTip: function (tip) {
        this.$axios.post(this.$API_URL + 'tips', {
            name: tip.name,
            description: tip.description
        }, {
            headers: {
                'Api-Token': this.$store.state.token
            }
        })
        .then( (response) => {
            this.tip_temporal.tip_id = response.data.tip_id
            this.$toastr.success('The Tip has been created successfully!', "Success!");
            this.finishAction()
        })
        .catch(error => {
            this.errorAction(error)
        });
    },
```

Lo que deseo hacer es que, en vez de la asignación

```
this.tip_temporal.tip_id = response.data.tip_id
```

mi método pueda retornar ese valor, algo así:

```
return response.data.tip_id
```

La idea es que, en alguna otra parte del codigo yo pueda hacer algo como esto:

```
let id = this.createTip(tip)
```

Intente hacer el `return` en el `then` de la promesa que genera axios, pero como todos sabemos, las promesas son asíncronas, así que siempre que intento asignar el valor que el método debería retornar, me asigna un valor indefinido.

¿Alguna idea?

Comment: deberías hacer return a la promise en general, y ella dará respuesta según como se resuelva, siendo el response o el catch de la siguiente forma: `return this.$axios.`

Comment: más cómodo es usar async await

Comment: ¿Es necesario esperar a que termine y te el ID? ¿no te sería útil hacerlo con eventos? Por ejemplo, lanzas el evento de tripcreated al ser creado y al escucharlo haces lo que necesitas hacer.

Comment: @ManueldelaCruz Si, es necesario. Con eventos a que te refieres? Al bus o algo similar?

Comment: así es, ya sea que el evento sea del componente o del EventBus

Comment: Esto es una sobreutilizacion de lo que ya hace vue por si mismo.. la reactividad hace eso mismo que vos queres escribir en codigo. Porque querrias hacer algo asi?

Comment: @gbianchi porque este metodo esta en un mixin que ayuda a varios componentes, y no quiero depender de los componentes, sino que el propio mixin tengo un pequeño nivel de independencia que resulte en mi favor.

Comment: Creo que eso era informacion necesaria para la pregunta. Pq de no ser asi, vue lo resuelve solo. Recuerda aceptar la respuesta si sirvio.

Comment: @gbianchi quizas si era, lo tendre en cuenta para la proxima pregunta. Claro, aceptare la respuesta. Gracias por la participacion, veo que hay poco interes por Vue aqui y es una de las etiquetas que sigo y que buscare promover.

Comment: Poco interes? Tenemos hasta una sala de chat :). Lo que pasa es que es tan simple que no hay mucho que preguntar. Lo que hiciste ahora se solucionaria en vue 3 cuando no dependas de un mixin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilizo promise con funciones async y await para que espere los resultados y los asigne, cuando llames al mismo con otra funcion tambien tiene que ser async y await.
Aconsejo leer un poco mas de promise ya que es un tema medio complejo.

```
createTip: async function (tip) {
       let respuesta = await new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
        this.$axios.post(this.$API_URL + 'tips', {
            name: tip.name,
            description: tip.description
        }, {
            headers: {
                'Api-Token': this.$store.state.token
            }
        })
        .then( (response) => {
            resolve(response.data.tip_id)
        })
        .catch(error => {
            reject(error)
        });
})
return respuesta;
    },
```

Comment: Buena respuesta, lo he terminado haciendo asi, solamente que en vez de guardar la promesa en una variable, la retorno de una vez.

Comment: @KennyBarrera excelente, me alegro que te sirva :D. Si podes marcarlo como respuesta.